# What is the best way to create text based Android apps?

Tags: android

I am working on an Android app which will store long texts, images etc. A 'guide' app in other words. But I am not sure which one would be the best way(or the most logical way) to do this. Storing the texts in strings.xml, using HTML&CSS and showing it using WebView, using databases, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends a bit on where the text is coming from, IMHO.

If the text is baked into the app, and it will only change via an update to the app itself, I'd use HTML/CSS and store it in `assets/`. They can then be loaded using `loadUrl("file:///android_asset/...")` in a `WebView`. If you wanted full-text search, you could prepare a SQLite database with an FTS table and package that with the app as well, unpacking and using it on the first run of the app.

If you plan on downloading the text, then the decision hinges more on what the server is serving, as you're probably stuck with that format. That, in turn, would influence the storage approach.

String resources (strings.xml) are fairly clunky for long bits of text.